# Installing Debian over Ubuntu with encrypted /home partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, encryption, debian-jessie

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 which I have setup with a separate encrypted /home partition. Now I want to install Debian 8 without formatting and/or deleting my /home partition. How do I do this?

Prior to Ubuntu I was using LinuxMint 18 and all I had to do to switch to Ubuntu was set up my new system with the same user id's, usernames and passwords and it worked without my having to remove the /home partition. Can I also do the same with Debian? I have searched online but could not find any answers.

Comment: Yes, you can do this - Debian and Ubuntu are very similar (so installing Debian shouldn't make a bit difference, anyway). You just have to make sure you don't screw up the `/home` partition during installation, and if it doesn't work on first attempt (though I expect it would), you may have to look at how the encryption is handled. I can't give step-by-step instructions, though.

Comment: The ecryptfs versions may not match, not sure if that would matter though. But whatever happens make a backup of your home files FIRST (unless you don't care if they're deleted) and check that it's readable